# how to i call "self.something method" in ruby

Tags: ruby, methods

when i call the MyClock.tick method it give me an "undefined method 'tick' for #  " Error

how do i call a method that has "self.something" as the method name, or is that not the problem here?

```
class Clock

  attr_accessor :hours, :mins, :secs, :time 

  def initialize file_name
    @time = IO.readlines("clock.dat")

    @hours = @time[0].to_i     # change values in array to ints
    @mins = @time[1].to_i
    @secs = @time[2].to_i
  end

  def self.tick
    @sec = @sec + 1 # add on sec to the clock

    if @secs > 59
      @mins = @mins + @secs/60   # change to min from sec
      @secs = 0 + @secs%60
    end

    if @mins > 59
      @hours = @hours + @hours/60  #change to hour from min
      @mins = 0 + @mins%60
    end

    if @hours > 23    #make sure not more then 24 hours
      @hours = 0 + @hours%24
    end
  end

  def self.to_s
    puts ("#{@hours}:#{@mins}:#{@secs}")   # prints time
  end

end

MyClock = Clock.new "clock.dat"

MyClock.tick

MyClock.to_s
```

Comment: Please use capitals for the start of sentences and for "i".

Comment: Don't call `puts()` inside your `#to_s` (once you make that an instance method).  Instead return a string and let the caller print if/as needed.

Answer (score 2):

First, name your instance variable with all lower case:

```
my_clock = Clock.new "clock.dat"
```

Next, fix class/instance methods. You probably want an instance method:

```
def tick
```

instead of class method

```
def self.tick
```

Comment: Nitpick: an instance variable is prefixed with an `@`, as opposed to the local variable `my_clock` that holds a reference to an instance of `Clock`.

Comment: And it should be noted that `def self.to_s` has also to be just `def to_s`.

Comment: @MichaelKohl..why do we need an instance variable to store the value of new instance of Clock class? `my_clock = Clock.new "clock.dat"` will be similar to `a = []` or `a = Array.new`, right?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call class method from objects.
Use this:

```
Clock.tick
```

if you want to call class method, or this

```
class Clock
  def tick
  end
end

Clock.new.tick
```

to call instance method

Comment: I think the OP wants to create an instance of a Clock, and call `tick` on it.

Answer (score 0):

The "best" way (or, rather, the least bad) that I've found is to retrieve the class of the object using the 'class' method, then call the self-method. For example:

```
class Clock
  def self.tick
    puts "This is self.tick"
  end

  # Example of call from non-self function to a self-function.
  def test
    # Note: Call from a member function needs the "self.", otherwise
    # "class" will be interpreted as the keyword "class".
    self.class.tick
  end
end

my_clock = Clock.new
my_clock.test
# Example of a call to a class-self-function from an object.
my_clock.class.tick
```

Update: One can, of course, call `Clock.tick`. However, explicitly specifying the class name when one does not have to makes things like refactoring harder. This is also the reason why class methods often are defined using `def self.tick` rather than `def Clock.tick`.

Comment: This is not the "best way", nor the least bad one. This is simply how Ruby works: a method defined as `self.something` is a *class method*, which means that you can call it on the class itself, **and not on any of its instances**. 

Note that class methods can also be defined as `Clock.tick` instead of `self.tick`, although this would probably cause some issue when subclassing.

Also, note that the class object on which you are calling a class method does not know anything about instance attributes (the `@` variables).

Comment: Everything you say is correct. However, in practice, when implementing a class, some methods will be instance methods and some class methods, and often one would like to call a class method from an instance method. Personally, I don't like to include the class name itself in the call, as it would introduce problems when performing refactoring. Also, in languages like C++, an instance method can call a class (i.e. static) method directly, and the naming scheme I provided in my answer is the closest to what I want to achieve (without resorting to Ruby tricks like implementing `method_missing`.)

Comment: I was not suggesting to include the class name itself in the call. I only talked about `def Clock.tick` to clarify the meaning of `def self.tick`. I agree with the rest you say, apart the fact that this Clock example doesn't fit very well with the concept of a *useful* and *meaningful* class method.

Answer (score 0):

To begin, Ruby conduct says to never use constants for local variables like you just did. A capital letter at the beginning of an identifier makes it a constant.
When you declare your `tick` method, you are declaring it as a class method, which means it would be called with `Clock.tick` rather than `my_clock.tick`. If you want the method to be used with `my_clock.tick`, remove the `self.` in the method name.